# String to Date Format as DD/MM/YYY in Python - Portuguese

Tags: windows, python-3.x, date-formatting, locate

I would like to convert the string "23/02/2018" to a date format as 23-fev-2018.

Most importanly is that, the month must be in portuguese language, refering to fevereiro.

My issue is that usually the datetime.date prints like (YYYY,MM,DD):

```
import datetime 
datestr = "23/02/2018" 
dateobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datestr, "%d/%m/%Y")
print dateobj #year, month, day
```

How may I print from a string as 23/10/2017 to date format as 23-out-2017, refering to the month "outubro" in portuguese?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the locale module.

```
import locale
import datetime

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_pt.UTF-8')
datetime.datetime.strptime('23/10/2017', '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%d/%B/%Y')
# '23/Outubro/2017'
datetime.datetime.strptime('23/10/2017', '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%d/%b/%Y')
# '23/Out/2017'
```

Comment: What's wrong with mine?

> import locale
> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_pt.UTF-8')
> datestr = "23/10/2017"
> date = datetime.datetime.strptime(datestr, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%d/%b/%Y')
> print (date)

Comment: The bug is called in line 2:
> locale.Error: unsupported locale setting

Please, may I have to install any module via command line?

Comment: You should check your locales using `[(l, ll) for l, ll in  locale.locale_alias.items() if 'pt' in l]`

Comment: Please, I have two comments: [...] 1st) I've seen that the locale.locale_alias does not work in Windows. I still do not know what to do. [...] 2nd) One step back, the strftime prints a string type variable, which is not what I want. I would like to have a date type variable in order to write it on a .xls file. [...] Note: When I write a date type variable on .xls file, It displays as "43182".